# Помогите в решении задания на языке C++

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно решить задание на C++. Нет никаких мыслей по поводу (строго не судите, студент 1 курса)

Comment: хотя бы не поленились и напечатали условие текстом. А решение простое. А потом вдруг находится раз - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0 и два - https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5

Comment: @KoVadim, я просто аплодирую Вашему ответу!

Comment: а можно просто Кнута прочитать. там есть эта задача. Хотя она легко решается рекурсивно. Достаточно немножко подумать

Comment: @KoVadim На всякий случай уточню, что по вашим ссылкам не генерация всех вариантов, а указание количества разбиений. Я бы рекомендовал раздел 7.2.1.4, тома 4а "*Искусства программирования*"; впрочем, непосредственного алгоритма построения в лексикографическом порядке там нет, только в обратном лексикографическом. Но в целом вы правы - решение несложное, особенно при использовании рекурсии (намек для ТС). Кстати, Артём, вы бы прочли хоть первую страницу сайта - а то неудобно как-то, без единого значка ходить. И еще - в таких задачах лучше сразу приводить URL проверяющей системы.

Comment: Ну не могу же я прямо готовое решение дать человеку, который поленился и дал задачу свою картинкой?

Answer (score 0):

```
void generate(int N, int max, string s = "") {
    if (N == 0) {
        cout << s << endl;
        return;
        }

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
        if (i > max) break;

        string r = s + " " + to_string(i);
        generate(N - i, i, r);
        }
    }

int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    generate(N, N);
    }
```